# Rails: Match a route prefixing all my other routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm migrating a Rails application to JRuby running on TorqueBox.

As a result I am now running locally as `http://localhost:8080/myapp/` instead of the previous `http://localhost:3000/`.

As a result none of my routes match.

Is there a quick way to take into account this change without having to rewrite all my routes considering I will be running this from `/` eventually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/myapp"` in the appropriate environment file. In this case, it sounds like it would be `config/environments/development.rb`. Once you deploy somewhere else and want to use `/` as your root URL again, just make sure the app is running in the production environment, and it'll work as expected.